# Images scale but then disappear in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

On this page:  http://www.jvillacompany.com/gallery.html in FIREFOX only the images scale but then disappear.

It works fine in Chrome and IE.  I have read other answers to similar problems but still can not figure this out.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Working fine for me in Firefox.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I am using a mac and latest FF, was not able to reproduce

Comment: You do have a syntax error. The the *scr*-attribute of the `<script>`-tag that tries to include jQuery from Google isn't closed properly, a `"` is missing. And you also try to include jQuery two times in different versions, which may not be a good idea.

Comment: I CAN repro on Win 8 latest FF, they sometimes stay and sometimes multiple disappear at once

Comment: <section class="thumbImage">
                     <div><span class="iconWrapper iconLink"></span></div>
                     <img src="assets/images/portfolio/portfolio-img-09.jpg" alt="" class="scale-with-grid" />
                    </section>
CSS:
.thumbImage {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 50px;
      border-radius: 6px 50px;
}
.thumbImage img{
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 50px;
      border-radius: 6px 50px;
}
}

Comment: I don't know how to fix that jQuery issue.  Where do I go to see that?
Also the .thumbImage img css has two entries it seems.  Here's another one:
.thumbImage img {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

Comment: @AndreaBarnes Can you update the question with this code? It's very unreadable in comment format.